# SOAP webservice always returning status 500 in all clients except one

Tags: java, xml

I hope someone can help me and maybe give me some hints on this.

So I currently develop a portlet application in Java which relies on a remote SOAP-bases webservice. The application posts xml to get data from it, works with the data and then posts it back to the webservice.

But for some reason I can't get a 'correct' response from it or at least some expected result. I always get a SOAP response with code 500 (internal server error) and some SOAP fault message (which is defined by the hoster/dev of the web service). I also know exactly which response I am to expect.

I have access to the documentation and wsdl document, so I am very certain that my request body (which is in text/xml) is correct.
Also, I managed to get a correct response from the webservice by using the SOAP client on http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html (defining the wsdl and using the generated HTML form). But when using any other client like SoapUI, Wizdler (Chrome extension) or Postman or implementing the call in Java I get 'Status 500' back.
In past projects, at least SoapUI worked for me. I also tried posting the request xml document as one line or as beautified xml, no effect.

I have no access to the server hosting the webservice, so can't look into logs etc.
One thing to note is that the webservice uses https.

Another thing is that the documentation and an employee of the hoster tell me to append a parameter to the url like this: 'https://host:port/path_to_wsdl' -nohostverify
But I cannot see how as there is nothing else specified.

Maybe someone had similar problems before or has some clue about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself (admittedly a while back, so my solution comes quite late). For anyone who has a similar problem:

as it turns out, the webservice is not expecting plain xml. The  relevant part of the request must be of type 'String', meaning that a specific xml element in the soap body does not contain further (normal) xml elements, but the necessary xml elements with all special characters encoded as HTML numbers.

Example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   soapenv:Body>
      <urn:webserviceNode>
          <requestContent xsi:type="xsd:String">
              &lt;subnode_A xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;&gt;
                  &lt;subnode_A1&gt;some_string&lt;/subnode_A1&gt;
                  &lt;subnode_A2&gt;another_string&lt;/subnode_A2&gt;
              &lt;/subnode_A&gt;
          </requestContent>
      </urn:webserviceNode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I didn't recognize this until I inspected the response of the successful request and found that the web soap-client was masking the html-encoded xml chars.
Note that here, also quotation marks (and umlauts for us here in germany) are affected.

So I "only" had to replace all special characters in parts of the soap request to make a successful request.

I don't know if this is common or not but I doubt that this is common practice and I can not think of a reason why implementing a webservice like that would  be necessary.

Anyway, case closed.